# File not found by Rails asset pipeline despite referencing it appropriately

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fonts, asset-pipeline

I've created a 'fonts' folder within app/assets in my Rails application. The folder contains both TTF and WOFF files plus a SCSS file ("stylesheet.scss") that declares and references those custom font types I'd like to use in my views.

In order to have access to this new folder I've done the following modifications:

**config/application.rb**

I've added a new path within Application class as below

```
class Application < Rails::Application
  config.load_defaults 5.1
  config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "fonts")
end
```

**app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss**

I've referenced 'stylesheet.scss' as below:

```
/*
  *= require fonts/stylesheet.scss
*/
```

When I load my app however, I get the following error: 
"couldn't find file 'fonts/stylesheet.scss' with type 'text/css"
This happens despite confirming below that the path 'app/assets/fonts' was in fact checked.

I've tried removing the 'scss' extension form the 'require' line and importing the file with `@import "fonts/stylesheet";` instead with no luck.

Any idea on what I'm doing wrong would be appreciated.

Comment: May you try to rename `fonts/stylesheet.scss` to `fonts/stylesheet.css.scss` ?

Comment: Thanks @cnnr it didn't work. However, I just found that I don't need to reference the path in such a way that includes the folder name it worked by using `@import "stylesheet";`

Answer (score 0):

I just found that I don't need to reference the path in such a way that includes the folder name it worked by referencing the file name alone like below.

```
@import "stylesheet";
```

I wonder what happens if two files share the same name but are located in different folders within app.

Comment: You should not have 2 files with the same name

Comment: what will happen is only 1 file will be loaded. This can happen when you have a `main.js` and a `main.coffee`, because the scaffold generator `rails g scaffold main` will generate also `coffeescript` and `scss` files for `main`, then maybe later you want to have `main.js`, but when you `require 'main'`  only the `main.coffee` will be included